# How can i have my custom "type" in symfony2 forms entity select box

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the normal way to show select box

```
add('user','entity')
```

When i want to use checkboxes then i don't like the style it uses.

So i want that if i use my custom type i.e

`add('user','MYTYPE')` Then i can define my own way of how to display various entities

I am using `Genemuformbundle` and iwas using his custom types like `genemu_jquerychosen_entity` to override how the fields display.

But i could not understand , how to make my own

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a custom field follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) cookbook entry.